# How to create a custom Iterator in Java?

Tags: java, object, iterator, iterable

I've this problem:

> Given the iterable `class Foo`, which keeps always only one `int`
>   value which is set on its constructor, make an iterator so it
>   respects all of its restrictions which are: you can't change the `int`
>   value after its initialization. You should include only the required
>   exceptions to be thrown.

Ok, so far, if I understood the question the right way, I should create an iterator for that `Foo` class, however I've never done this before and it seems to be that the question itself is a bit misleading. Is it a list? Or shouldn't it be? Anyway, despite that, all I want to know is how to create it.

So now I've this:

```
public class Foo implements Iterable<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {   
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
}
```

But I don't even know if this is the right way to do so. 
I'd be very appreciated if someone could help me out with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'Include all of the required exceptions to be thrown but only those that are needed' appears to be contradictory. Seek clarification.

Comment: The return type of the `iterator()` method should be `Iterator<Something>`. 
 Should it be `Iterator<Foo>` or `Iterator<Integer>` or something else?

Comment: Edited. It means that I only want the needed for this class iterator restrictions and not all. I don't know if I'm saying it the right way.

Comment: Well, the exercise only tells what I quoted above, so I believe it is Iterator<Foo> ?

Comment: So what should happen when we iterate through a `Foo` instance? Nothing?

Comment: It's not stated... I believe this is only to teach/train how to make a costume iterator. I'd say it should go through a List<Foo> somehow. But these Foo are the costume ones. For the matter of the exercise it will be okay if I just understand how to create a proper iterator for any-generic class. A nice example with some random class and its costume iterator would be enough. :)

Comment: The word is 'custom', not 'costume'. I've already correct that in your post. You need to seek clarification about the exceptions. I would. I don't understand it.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, it means that from all the exceptions that an iterator might throw, I only need to throw those that are indeed required. That’s what I understood. As I said, that quoted in the post is the question I have. I don’t have any more info beside that. :/

Comment: Then, as I will now have told you on three separate occasions, you need to seek clarification from the source of the question. Nobody else can do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal example would be to return an empty iterator, whose `hasNext()` always returns `false` and `next()` will throw `NoSuchElementException`.

```
public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Foo>() {
        public boolean hasNext() { 
            return false;
        }
        public Foo next() {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    };
}
```

Of course most iterators have states. For example you can iterate from `0` to the integer value the `Foo` instance holds.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Foo implements Iterable<Foo> {
    private final int value;

    public Foo(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Foo>() {
            private Foo foo = new Foo(0);

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return foo.value < Foo.this.value;
            }

            @Override
            public Foo next() {
                if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();

                Foo cur = foo;
                foo = new Foo(cur.value+1);
                return cur;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(10);
        for (Foo f: foo) {
            System.out.println(f.value);
        }
    }
}
```